# How to generate X_train for SVR by using for-loop at every iteration of the loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have datasets that have more than 2000 rows and 23 columns including the `age` column. I have generated `X_train` for SVR. Now, I need to generate `X_train` by taking the rows 2-1001 of the dataset. Basically I shift my X_train by one step on the dataset. And the other data i.e. `y_train, X_test, y_test` should be shifted as well. Once it is completed I need to do it for the rows `3-1002`. And I need to follow this procedure until the end of the dataset.

```
#I need to put the below lines  in a for loop
X_train, y_train = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]
X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001] 

X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
print(X_test.shape)


SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
y_pred

#in a for loop and change the indexes in lines 
X_train, y_train = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000] and
X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001]
```

that is at every iteration of the loop. Now I am stuck down in this situation. My way of wringing is correct or not?   How may I write the code for this condition?

Code from the beginning:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Make fake dataset
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2000,22))
dataset['age'] = np.random.randint(2, size=2000)

# Separate the target from the other features
target = dataset['age']
data = dataset.drop('age', axis = 1)

X_train, y_train = data.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]

X_test,  y_test  = data.loc[1001], target.loc[1001] 

X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
print(X_test.shape)

SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
y_pred
```

Code for current work:

```
for i in range(1, 1001):

        X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]
        X_test, y_test = dataset.loc[i], target.loc[i]
        X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
        print(X_test.shape)

        SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
        SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
        y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)

Output: KeyError: 1
```

Comment: @desertnaut please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case perfectly matches with `TimeSeriesSplit` cross validation. In your case, each fold size is 1 datapoint.

By default, the training data size would increase by 1 fold in each iteration. See the example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#time-series-split).

You just have to skip the initial 1000 iterations and then use the remaining. since, `TimeSeriesSplit` returns a generator, you could use the `islice` to get the elements from `1000` to `1999`.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from itertools import slice

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(max_train_size=1000, n_splits=1999)

for train_index, test_index in islice(tscv.split(X),1000, 2000):
    <do your stuff here>
```

Complete example:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.svm import SVR

# Make fake dataset
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data= np.random.rand(2000,22))
dataset['age'] = np.random.randint(2, size=2000)

# Separate the target from the other features
target = dataset['age']
data = dataset.drop('age', axis = 1)

tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(max_train_size=1000, n_splits=1999)

for train_index, test_index in islice(tscv.split(dataset.index),1000, 2000):
    X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[train_index], target.loc[train_index]
    X_test, y_test = dataset.loc[test_index], target.loc[test_index]
    X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(1, -1)
    SupportVectorRefModel = SVR()
    SupportVectorRefModel.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = SupportVectorRefModel.predict(X_test)
    print(test_index)
```

for some reason, if you want to use `for` loops, try this

```
for i in range(1, 1001):
    X_train, y_train = data.iloc[i:1000+i], target.iloc[i:1000+i]
    X_test, y_test = data.iloc[1000+i], target.iloc[1000+i]
```

Comment: Dear mentor, it is possible to write the code based on for loop. I am progressing on the way. I opened another question related to this. Please may check the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013214/how-to-add-some-offset-to-i-i-e-the-index-should-be-isome-number

Comment: `X_train` and `y_train` should be changed at every iteration. So I should not write` static integers` as `indexes`. Their `indexes` should depend on` i`. For this reason, I write the line as


`X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:i], target.loc[:i]`;

`#Instead of 
X_train, y_train = dataset.loc[:1000], target.loc[:1000]`

So now, I need to add some `offset` to i. i.e. the` index` should be `[i+some_number]` what I can easily find that `some_number` as the test sample is the next line after the finishing of `X_train`. After completing this task my work will be done.

Comment: even in the suggested solution, it is not static integers, it is going to change in every iteration of `islice(tscv.split(X),1000, 2000)`.

Comment: updated my answer to show case how to use for loop.

Comment: while I use the `TimeseriesSplit` it shows an `error` because for `train_index, test_index in islice(tscv.split(X),1000, 2000):`  X is undefined. 

`NameError: name 'X' is not defined`

What should have to `mention` in terms of `X`?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. replace it with `dataset.index`

Comment: it shows an error "ValueError: X.shape[1] = 232 should be equal to 58, the number of features at training time"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214657/discussion-between-venkatachalam-and-user13598750).